# Is there a way to flag only specific C# properties as serializable?

Tags: c#, json.net

`[JsonIgnore]` will prevent a certain C# model property from being included in the JSON serialization. I'm attempting to have ALL properties on a model ignored UNLESS they have a `[JsonInclude]` property, so it's more of an "opt-in" rather than "opt-out" scenario.

Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Apply the following attribute to the model:

```
[JsonObject(MemberSerialization.OptIn)]
```

Then decorate each property you want included with the `JsonProperty` attribute.

[Documentation on `JsonObjectAttribute`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/JsonObjectAttributeOptIn.htm)