# Include properties in json serialization instead of ignoring others

Tags: c#, serialization, json.net

I know I can use `[JsonIgnore]` to exclude properties from being serialized but in my current use-case it'd be just easier and more robust if I just told the serializer which properties it should include (there are not only fewer of them but they also won't change in future).

So I was wondering, is there an opposite mechanism where I could **include** properties I need? I was thinking maybe I could use an interface or something but I'm not sure how to handle this. I need the original *big* object along the way but only its *lite* vesion should be serialized. How would I **conveniently** achieve this?

```cs
class Car
{
    [JsonInclude] // There is no such attribute but maybe another trick?
    public string Make { get; set; }

    public string MakeFormatted => Make.ToUpper().ToLower(); // anything
}
```

Comment: You'll want [JsonObjectAttribute opt-in serialization](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/JsonObjectAttributeOptIn.htm).

Comment: You can use an interface with the small part of properties you want to deserialize.

Comment: @Filburt cool. I tried this out and it's exactly how I wanted it to work. I used the `JsonObject` before with `IEnumerables` to not deserialize them as such but didn't see this parameter. Thanks ;-)

Comment: Found an existing question with an answer [Is there a way to flag only specific C# properties as serializable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52063717/is-there-a-way-to-flag-only-specific-c-sharp-properties-as-serializable)